# Output layer from PyQGIS 3 processing script is empty

Tags: python, qgis-processing, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I've created a processing script in QGIS 3, and although my output layer has shows a feature count greater than zero when using the feedback command, the resulting feature layer that appears in QGIS has no features. What am I doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##source_layer=vector
##output_layer=output vector

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        feedback.pushInfo('CRS is {}'.format(source.sourceCrs().authid()))

        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))


        sink=processing.run("native:buffer", {
            'INPUT': source,
            'DISTANCE': -4.0,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
        }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        feedback.pushInfo('sink output number of features is {}'.format(sink.featureCount()))

        results = {}
        results[self.OUTPUT] = sink
        return results
```

Subsequently, I've tried changing the last section to:

```
    bufferedLayer=processing.run("native:buffer", {
        'INPUT': source,
        'DISTANCE': -4.0,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'DISSOLVE': False,
        'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']
    }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
    feedback.pushInfo('sink output number of features is {}'.format(bufferedLayer.featureCount()))

    return {self.OUTPUT: bufferedLayer}
```

The function down gives the gives an error when it runs. Here is the output log for the function:

> Processing algorithm…
>   Algorithm 'My Script' starting…
>   Input parameters:
>   {'INPUT':'C:/GIS/VBS/map_nsc_geotypical_ne_europe/map_nsc_geotypical_ne_europe_shared/source/multimap/tiles_3x3/mapframes/gce_3x3_001_001.shp', 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:' }
>   CRS is EPSG:32634
>   Results: {'OUTPUT': 'output_7cd8f3b7_6e2b_457b_be6b_da9c71439756'}
>   sink output number of features is 1
>   Execution completed in 0.03 seconds
>   Results:
>   {'OUTPUT': }
>
> Loading resulting layers
>   `The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>output_7cd8f3b7_6e2b_457b_be6b_da9c71439756</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.`

I've tried following Jochen's suggestion of using an output rather than a parameter. By doing this the script window changes from this:
[image]
to this, it no longer has the option to specify the output layer:
[image]

Running the script also causes QGIS to crash :/

Comment: I think you have created a processing script in *QGIS 3*, not in *ARCGIS 3*, which has long since departed...

Comment: @M Bentley Did 2nd try solve your problem?

Comment: @jochen-schwarze  - That did work, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some reasearching I found that the key problem seems to be that you first defined `sink`

```
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink( ...
```

and later on overwrite it with the result of `processing.run...`

```
sink=processing.run("native:buffer", { ...
```

I tried the following which worked for me:

```
#create a temporary layer as a processing result
lyr = processing.run("native:buffer", {
        'INPUT': source,
        'DISTANCE': 40,
        'SEGMENTS': 5,
        'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
        'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
        'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
        'DISSOLVE': False,
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
    }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

    feedback.pushInfo('sink output number of features is {}'.format(lyr.featureCount()))

# and then copy the content of the temporary processing result into the output sink    
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    sink.addFeature(f)
```

Note that when you define the output sink as follows

```
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
        parameters,
        self.OUTPUT,
        context,
        source.fields(),
        source.wkbType(),
        source.sourceCrs()
    )
```

you are restricted to the geometry type of the source layer (`source.wkbType()`), which may cause problems (crash) when you try to buffer e.g. a point layer.

But with the mentioned slight alterations your script works:

[image]

Comment: Yes this works for me too! Thank you. I had avoided iterating through the features because I thought this could be computationally heavy. I guess I don't entirely understand what the outputSink is - it obviously has a specific purpose.